# How do I check that the radio button values are not changed in the inspector using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have attempted using this PHP

```
if ($_POST['use'] != 'Photo/Video Editing' || $_POST['use'] != 'Gaming' || $_POST['use'] != 'General Purpose' || $_POST['use'] != 'Streaming') {
  echo "<p>You have changed the options - Input Invalid</p>";
} else
//Run what would normally happen
```

for this HTML

```
  <fieldset class="qwrapper">
          <legend class="ctext">What is the main use case for your computer?</legend>
          <input required  type="radio" name="use" value="Photo/Video Editing"> Photo/Video Editing
          <br>
          <input required  type="radio" name="use" value="Gaming"> Gaming
          <br>
          <input required  type="radio" name="use" value="General Purpose"> General Purpose
          <br>
          <input required  type="radio" name="use" value="Streaming"> Media Machine
          <br>

        </fieldset>
```

This code results in the php echoing 'You changed the options - input invalid' even when I haven't actually changed the values in the inspector to test.

Comment: you are checking with `||` equals to `OR`. so it will always fail

Comment: @Sysix what do you mean? I thought I should use || because it cannot be all 4 options at once. What other operator should I use?

Comment: Your condition will always be true. If it's equal to one value, then it's not equal to the other values, so those parts of the condition will be true.

Comment: You should use `&&`.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you.

Comment: check part by part, is the first condition false? Yes, because it has "Pohto/Video Editing". Then go to your next condition, it must be true, because the first one was already false.

Comment: A check like this should probably rather use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php to begin with.